# React JS- hide description div unless corresponding card is dealt

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, 2d-games, playing-cards

React Question: I am trying to implement this method of activating divs based on whether or not a card gets dealt. So the plan is that there would be a SpellDescription in the div, and if the card count is greater than 0 (there are only one of each card) then the div would show.   I was going to take this example:

```
const Home = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {(() => {
        if (posts) {
          return <Posts posts={posts} />;
        } else {
          return <NoPosts />;
        }
      })()}
    </div>
  );
```

...... and then switch it to something like this:

```
const Awaken = ({ awakenCount }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {(() => {  {awakenCount && <Posts awakenCount={awakenCount}>{
    <strong>Awaken:  </strong><p>Choose a player, they discard 2 ingredients of their choice.</p>
    }</Posts>
      }  {
        !awakenCount && <NoPosts />
      };
    })

  }</div> );
}
```

I'm getting all sorts of errors about this. Not really sure what I am supposed to put in "Posts" or where the {s and (s are supposed to end. Sometimes Posts comes up as undefined, sometimes not.
Is this better to be in the function or outside the function? Tried it both ways.

On a side note, my game will run without this code, however it will only run if there is an extra "}" that VS code highlights in red. So maybe that could be the issue too.

I'm calling the function in the return:

```
return (
<Awaken>
  <Posts/>
  <NoPosts/>
</Awaken>
)
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this:

```
const Awaken = ({ awakenCount }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {awakenCount && 
         <Posts awakenCount={awakenCount}>
           <strong>Awaken:  </strong><p>Choose a player, they discard 2 ingredients of their choice.</p>
         </Posts>}
      {!awakenCount && <NoPosts />}
  </div>);
}
```

and then you would just use it like this:

```
<Awaken awakenCount={2} />
```

Hope this helps.